# Killing webservices everytime I start my solution

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, webserver, taskkill

I have 5 services running when my application starts up in VS2010. And everytime I get this error:

> Error 24  Unable to copy file "C:\My
> Project\Main\Entities\bin\Debug\Test.Testing.dll" to
> "bin\Test.Testing.dll". The process cannot access the file
> 'bin\Test.Testing.dll' because it is being used by another process.
>
> Error 26  Unable to copy file "C:\My
> Project\Main\Entities\bin\Debug\Test.Testing1.dll" to
> "bin\Test.Testing1.dll". The process cannot access the file
> 'bin\Test.Testing1.dll' because it is being used by another process.
>
> Error 23  Unable to copy file "C:\My
> Project\Main\Entities\bin\Debug\Test.Testing2.dll" to
> "bin\Test.Testing2.dll". The process cannot access the file
> 'bin\Test.Testing2.dll' because it is being used by another process.
>
> Error 25  Unable to copy file "C:\My
> Project\Main\Entities\bin\Debug\Test.Testing3.dll" to
> "bin\Test.Testing3.dll". The process cannot access the file
> 'bin\Test.Testing3.dll' because it is being used by another process.
>
> Error 27  Unable to copy file "C:\My
> Project\Main\Entities\bin\Debug\Test.Testing4.dll" to
> "bin\Test.Testing4.dll". The process cannot access the file
> 'bin\Test.Testing4.dll' because it is being used by another process.

To kill these web services I have to create a 'bat' file: `taskkill /F /IM WebDev.WebServer40.EXE`

Does anyone has any idea why this happens. Seems like my web services dont stop whenever I close the application?

Comment: How do you close the application? Try clicking "Stop Debugging" in Visual Studio.

Comment: I did that. But the services are still running in my localhost.

Comment: So, from a clean start, you press F5, press "Stop debugging", and press F5 again, and the second time, you get errors in building the services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are talking about. 
Go to WCF Library Project properties, WCF options tab and uncheck the checkbox saying "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution".

Instead of this service host, if required, write console based hosts and run them from a different solution (at least thats what I did).

Answer (score 0):

The VS web server doesn't stop running when you stop Visual Studio. Are you firing off any separate threads? If you attach the debugger to the WebDev.WebServer40.EXE process you should be able to identify what code is still executing.

Comment: Yes. I already attached my debugger to the WebDev.WebServer40.EXE.